# In SQL Server is it possible to create a table that has a unique Id?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, temp-tables

My boss has assigned a SQL task to me and as I am new to SQL, I am struggling to know where to start.

Task: *Create a `Customer` table to hold the data written in the `#Customer` temporary table in the `PopulateCustomers` stored procedure. This table will also need to have a unique id to ensure multiple instances of the populate functionality can be run concurrently.*

I know how to create a table in SQL and I am guessing I can look in the `PopulateCustomer` stored procedure to know what data will be written in the temp `Customer` table in order to create columns for the `Customer` table.

But what I am really struggling with is the concept of a unique Id for a database table. I immediately thought primary key for each row in the table. Which my boss responded no, I didn't want to push for more as not to come across as a newbie.

I have tried to google this myself and all I keep coming up with is pages that tell me about identifiers vs primary keys. But nothing ever tells me about a table having its own unique ID unless its in reference to the rows within the table each having an Identifier or primary key. This is leading me to think that I am not searching for the right key word for what this functionality is.

The closest thing I found was here. http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/check-if-temporary-table-exists.html

This query looks to me like its creating a temp table with an id.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT)
```

I have not pasted any of my work queries because I really want to research myself and figure this out. I just want to make sure I am looking in the right direction with what term I need to search for to find out how to create a table that has a unique ID. Or maybe I have misinterpreted the task and there is no such thing.

Comment: Sounds like they are talking about unique instance of the table itself? In which case you don't need to worry about it. Multiple executions of the stored procedure can happen in parallel and they each get their own copy of the #Customers temp table

Comment: Seriously, trying to pretend you know what you are doing - when you don't - to your boss is asking for trouble. Have a conversation with them and get clear about what it is they want and what skills you need to learn to be able to do it. Asking us to try and clarify an instruction from your boss is madness and could just as easily lead you to doing something completely wrong.

Comment: It's a little confusing referring to "the" temp table since each server process gets its own copy, so there is no need to worry about "concurrency", it sounds like there is some crossed-wires that need resolving.

Comment: Thanks Martin Smith. So creating a normal table will be sufficient.

Comment: Yes Dale K it is risky but I want to try and figure out if creating a unique Id for a table is possible.

Comment: Creating a *normal* table is not sufficient, you will get a name clash. But a `#` temp table is unique to each session

Answer (score -1):

What I got from your story is that you need a table with an unique id, automatically generated, and use this id as the primary key.

This table can be created like:

```
create table example
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    other_data varchar(200)
)
```

The key terms here are:

- identity - for the `id` column be auto-incremented
- primary key - so SQL Server ensures this column is unique
- clustered - for all the data in this table be organized physically by this column (and make it faster to be searched by it)

Comment: I dont think this is the answer to my question. I am asking is it possible to create a table that HAS a unique id. Like a table row HAS an identity or primary key

Comment: Every table in SQL Server is unique by its name - you cannot have two tables - or any objects - with the same name so your requirement I suspect is miss-placed.